# How to disable a picture box once I clicked a button and an image has been inserted

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I have created a grid in a panel and added 42 picture boxes for a 6x7 grid, Every time I click a button for the row it inserts an image of a red or yellow checker. I am trying to make the button add another image of the other image on the box on top. I have created an array as a check feature to see which player has won.
My code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Connect4
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        int i = 1;

        int[,] a = new int[7, 6];
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void tableLayoutPanel1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (i %2 == 1)
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\ Documents\Desktop\PROJECT FOR LAPTOP\red.png");
                pictureBox1.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\ Documents\Desktop\PROJECT FOR LAPTOP=\yellow.png");
                pictureBox1.Enabled = false;
            }
            i++;

           
        }

        private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            int cols = 7;
            int rows = 6;
            int width = panel1.Width / cols;
            int height = panel1.Height / rows;
            for (int col = 1; col < cols; col++)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, new Point(col * width, 0), new Point(col * width, panel1.Height));
            }
            for (int row = 1; row < rows; row++)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, new Point(0, row * height), new Point(panel1.Width, row * height));
            }
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.SizeChanged += Panel1_SizeChanged;
            panel1.Paint += panel1_Paint;
        }

        private void Panel1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.Invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

This is what my design looks like so far(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rg8Vg.png)
The red changes to a yellow circle one the button is clicked

I was expecting for it put in a red counter image first and then when I clicked the same button it would add a yellow counter on the picture box on top of it

This is the Upper right to bottom left code:

```
if (!winFound) //if win is not found on horizontal check Right Diagonals 
        {
            //Diagonal Upper right to bottom left(2D Array)
            for (int row = 3; row < 5 && !winFound; row++)
            {
                rowFound = row;
                for (int col = 0; col <= 3 && !winFound; col++)
                {
                    colFound = col;
                    if (board[row, col] != null)
                    {
                        temp = true;
                        winFound =
                            (board[row, col] == board[row + 1, col + 1]) &&
                            (board[row, col] == board[row + 2, col + 2]) &&
                            (board[row, col] == board[row + 3, col + 3]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I am unsure on why it doesnt check win

Comment: Are the buttons at the bottom in the TableLayoutPanel, and the PBs in panel1 above?  At any rate, what is the placement PATTERN of your 42 pictureboxes? Did you use a naming convention that would allow you to determine the name of the PB at a specific column/row combination? I would have used something like pb00 for the bottom left and pb65 for the one in the top right, using pb[col][row] syntax.  So the first column of PBS from bottom to top would be pb00, pb01, pb02 to pb05. This way you can find the "next" available PB in a column by building the name, retrieving it, and checking the image.

Comment: It does from pb1 to pb42, where pb1 is bottom left and pb42 is top right, all the picture boxes are in the tablelayoutpanel

Comment: Okay. But where is pb2? Is it above or to the right of pb1?

Comment: to the right of pb1, I have stacked 6 buttons ontop of eachother and I have the connect 4, but I am unsure on how to make a check win feature using picture boxes I was going to try to use a 2d array

Comment: The 2D array is a good approach. You shouldn't check the win condition with the PBs. Once you set the PB you also set the corresponding location in the 2D array. Can you explain more about the six stacked buttons? Your picture looked like 7 buttons across the bottom, below each column. I thought you'd simply click the button of the column you want to place in.

Comment: I have the 7 across but there are 6 on top of each other in the 7 rows, so When I click one button it would hide the first and a second one would appear. So it would look like stacking

Comment: It would be easiest to have just the single row of 7 buttons across the bottom. As you click the button it can figure out which PB is the next available one up top.  You don't need 42 different buttons, and you can have common code for all the buttons.  I'll update my code to demonstrate, switching the PB layout so it matches your increasing numbers from left to right, going from bottom to top.

Comment: That was my plan the first time, I tried to do an if statement where it said if picture box1 had a value it would go to another one, but it failed

Comment: See my edited code below.

Comment: Sorry, for being annoying but I cant get the checkWin to work, I tried to use int Column and int Row to get all possible combinations and example was like: bool winner == false, if (row1 == row2)&&(row2 == row3 ==)&&(row3 == row4){ winner == true). So the winner == false means there isn't an automatic winner then the if statement was if there are 4 corresponding rows it allows a winner

Comment: You could UPDATE your original post above with your new CODE.  Then we can see where you are currently at and help you fix it.  If you update the post, please also include a brief description of the control layout if you changed from your original design.

Comment: I have added my first attempt onto it doing the check win feature. I didnt get any errors so I tried to see if it worked and it didnt

Comment: `if ((column == 1) && (column == 2) && (column == 3) && (column == 4))` Assuming "column" is an int, how could it possibly be equal to 1, 2, 3, and 4 at the same time?  If the first part was true, being equal to 1, then it can't possibly also be equal to any of the other parts.  What you need to do is inspect the CONTENTS of the 2D array at a specific row/col combination to the contents of the 2D array at a different row/col combination.  Your original post had `int[,] a` declared.  Are you using "a" to track the board state?  If so, what int values designate red vs. yellow? Zero is blank.

Comment: So I'd expect to see code like: `a[r,c] == a[y,x]`, which is checking if the contents at those two locations are equal.  Be careful that you don't blindly check for equality, though, since an Integer 2D array will initially hold all ZEROES and therefore you will get a match with all zeroes unless you specifically code to prevent that.

Comment: oh I thought that column == 1 would grab the first column and etc, So I thought it would get all 4 columns . For the int[,] a, I removed it since it was "never used" so I figured it was useless. but I am unsure on out to get the specific column and row to check if the user won.

Comment: Gotcha. In my example the board is represented with `String[,] board`.  A null there means the spot is empty, with "R" and "Y" present to indicate that color in the spot. So you could do something like `board[r,c] != null && board[r,c] == board[r2, c2] && board[r,c] == board[r3,c3] && ...etc...`.  Some kind of LOOPing structure would be good, not hard-coding every possible combination.  Good luck!

Comment: I have tried making a looping feature before and it didn’t work, I usually just settle for hard-coding every combination however it looks very ugly. Also are the [r, c] meant to be rows and columns? Would I define them as int ?

Comment: Correct; "r" stands for row and "c" means column. They would be declared as int. Would you like to see an example of the looping approach? I could show just checking for a horizontal win, then you could extrapolate and add in vertical and diagonal.

Comment: Yes please, I have asked other people in my class and no one can help me

Comment: See edited bottom half of 2nd post for an explanation of how to do the Upper Left to Bottom Right Diagonal check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the first column on the left is `pb1` at the bottom and `pb7` at the bottom right, and `button1` is on the left with `button7` on the right.

Here's how you'd do it with just ONE set of buttons across the bottom to pick which column to drop the next piece into:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private String[,] board = new String[6,7]; // six rows by seven columns 
    private int i = 1; // odd = red, even = yellow
    private List<Button> buttons;
    private Image red;// = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\ogisi\OneDrive - Wilmslow High School\Desktop\PROJECT FOR LAPTOP\red.png");
    private Image yellow;// = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\ogisi\OneDrive - Wilmslow High School\Desktop\PROJECT FOR LAPTOP\yellow.png");

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // only ONE row of buttons, from Left to Right, BELOW all the PictureBoxes
        // PBs are placed from left to right, bottom to top
        // pb1 is at bottom left, pb2 to its right, pb3 to its right, etc...
        // pb8 in second row from the bottom on the left, pb9 to its right, pb10 to its right, etc...
        // pb15 in third row from bottom on the left, etc..
        // pb42 is in the top row in the rightmost column
        buttons = new List<Button> { button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7 };
        foreach (Button btn in buttons)
        {
            btn.Click += Btn_Click;
        }
        nextTurnColor();
    }

    private void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        int column = buttons.IndexOf(btn);

        int rowPlaced = -1;
        for(int row=0; row<6; row++)
        {
            if(board[row,column] == null)
            {
                rowPlaced = row;
                board[row, column] = (i % 2 == 1) ? "R" : "Y";

                String pbPrefix = "pictureBox"; // "pb"
                String ctlName = pbPrefix + ((row * 7) + (column + 1));
                PictureBox pb = this.Controls.Find(ctlName, true).FirstOrDefault() as PictureBox;
                pb.BackColor = (i % 2 == 1) ? Color.Red : Color.Yellow;
                //pb.Image = (i % 2 == 1) ? red : yellow;
                if (row == 5)
                {
                    btn.Enabled = false; // column is full!
                }

                i++;                    
                break;
            }
        }
        if (rowPlaced != -1)
        {                
            // ... check "board" for a win condition ...

            // if no win, then change player
            nextTurnColor();
        }
    }

    private void nextTurnColor()
    {
        this.Text = (i % 2 == 1) ? "Red's turn." : "Yellow's turn.";
    }

}
```

Sample run: (*No win condition check being performed!)

[image]

Comment: I have made the board and I have used 42 buttons for each individual picturebox(I know it is extremely inefficient) But I don't know how to create a check win, I was to try and use the column number and see if the picture box are even or odd, But I dont know how to do that

Comment: This has both a 2D array for board state checking, and a single row of buttons across the bottom to pick the column to drop into. There are 42 PBs above the single row of buttons.  See description and comments for how they are laid out. Note that I have the Image portions commented out, and you'd need to change the "pbPrefix" value to match your PB naming syntax!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of checking for a horizontal win.

Read those comments carefully!

```
// an empty spot in the board will be null
// red spot will contain "R"
// yellow spot will contain "Y"
private String[,] board = new String[6, 7];

private void FooBar()
{
    // here is how to check for a horizontal win
    // we need to check each row, this is the outer loop
    // we need to check the columns, thus the inner loop
    // for four in a row, horizontally, we canstart anywhere
    // from column 0 up to  to column 3, but cannot start
    // from column 4 or above as there wouldn't be enough
    // room to finish the row of four
    //
    // 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
    // x x x x
    //       x x x x        
    //
    // board.getLength(0) tells us how many rows in 2D array
    // board.getLength(1) tells us how many columns in 2D array
    int rowFound = -1;
    int colFound = -1;
    bool winFound = false; // assume no win until proven otherwise
    for (int row = 0; row < board.GetLength(0) && !winFound; row++)
    {
        rowFound = row;
        for (int col = 0; col <= (board.GetLength(1) - 4) && !winFound; col++)
        {
            colFound = col;
            // we want to ignore any starting position that is blank
            // so we don't end up getting a four in a row "match"
            // because all of them are equal, but contain null
            if (board[row, col] != null)
            {
                // are the next 3 horizontally the same as the first?
                // we don't need to worry about an index out of bounds
                // here since we controlled the inner loop above
                // with "(board.GetLength(1) - 4)"
                // both loops will drop out if winFound becomes true!
                winFound =
                    (board[row, col] == board[row, col + 1]) &&
                    (board[row, col] == board[row, col + 2]) &&
                    (board[row, col] == board[row, col + 3]);                        
            }
        }        
    }      

    if (!winFound) {
        // ... check for vertical win in here ...
    }

    if (!winFound) {
        // ... check for diagonal win (upper left to bottom right) in here ...
    }

    if (!winFound) {
        // ... check for diagonal win (upper right to bottom left) in here ...
    }

    // if four in a row was never found, winFound will still be false
    if (winFound)
    {
        // ... there was a winner! ...
        String winner = board[rowFound, colFound];
        Console.WriteLine("The winner was: " + winner);
    }
}
```

Hopefully you can take this example and figure out how to apply it to a check for a vertical and/or diagonal win condition. Don't forget that when checking for a diagonal win you'd need to check for both an upper left to bottom right diagonal, and an upper right down to bottom left diagonal.

For the upper left to bottom right check, here's an image showing where possible starting positions could be:

[image]

For the rows, they only start between rows 3 and 5 inclusive. For the columns, they can only start between 0 and 3 inclusive. We need to take these constraints into account in our two for loops:

```
// Upper Left to Bottom Right Diagonal Check
for (int row = 3; row <= 5 && !winFound; row++)
{
    rowFound = row;
    for (int col = 0; col <= 3 && !winFound; col++)
    {
        colFound = col;
        if (board[row, col] != null)
        {
            // are the next 3 diagonal the same?
            // Upper Left to Bottom Right direction!
            winFound =
                (board[row, col] == board[row - 1, col + 1]) &&
                (board[row, col] == board[row - 2, col + 2]) &&
                (board[row, col] == board[row - 3, col + 3]);                        
        }
    }        
}
```

Here's one way to do the Upper Right to Bottom Left Diagonal check:

```
// Diagonal Check - Upper Right to Bottom Left:
for (int row = 3; row <= 5 && !winFound; row++)
{
    rowFound = row;
    for (int col = 3; col <= 6 && !winFound; col++)
    {
        colFound = col;
        if (board[row, col] != null)
        {
            // are the next 3 diagonal the same?
            // Upper Right to Bottom Left direction!
            winFound =
                (board[row, col] == board[row - 1, col - 1]) &&
                (board[row, col] == board[row - 2, col - 2]) &&
                (board[row, col] == board[row - 3, col - 3]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have done the vertical and the diagonal to top right to bottom left, I was doing the last one and I got an error, I will update my code above and show you what the error was and what I put in it

Comment: It worked thank you so much, You give very clear explanation.

Comment: Based on your code for upper left to bottom right, you might want to re-visit how you solved the vertical and the other diagonal.  ;)

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I didn't realise you added a comment. I have done the coding I have done the vertical one, horizontal and Upper left to bottom right, I thought I did the Upper right to bottom left correct because when I was testing it didn't say out of bound but I realised that it doesnt actually check if they win, I figured if I swapped the values around from the other diagonal it would work but it didn't. I have updated the code above

Comment: I added the Upper Right to Bottom Left check.